# Developer Survey "Languages Over Time" graph title emboldening is confusing

Tags: discussion, survey-2017

In the [Stack Overflow Developer Survey Results 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/), the [Languages Over Time](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/#technology-languages-over-time) graph ([direct link to the .SVG used on the page](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Research/Img/2017/HistoricalLanguages.svg?v=250eedb72493)) shows the popularity of ten languages over time as ten separate graphs.

The names of the bottom five are emboldened whereas the names of the top five are not, which makes it look weird/confusing:

> [image: Languages Over Time graph]

Either the names of all ten languages should be emboldened, or none of them should.